How to eliminate flow streams?
I work via the Qgis modeler with SAGA algos on flows from DEM to determine the watershed at a given outlet.
I know how to get the watershed (capture1),

I know how to create an obstacle to flow and see the effect on the watershed (we see the retention effect, capture 2).


I would like to remove part of the flows by creating a sort of bottomless hole or trench (this made it possible to simulate a rainwater network capturing and managing flows). The flows would not be retained and would disappear...
I tried to make a sort of hole with a polygon having a negative altimetry or to delete the DEM data from a polygon... but I obtained a result close to that of the obstacle.
Do you have an idea?
